# SimpleXML and namespaces

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have following code.

```
 <entry>
  <job:location>
   <job:id>24</job:id>
   <job:region>6</job:region>
  </job:location>
 </entry>
```

I've problem with namespaces. How I can read content of job:region tag in SimpleXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php 
    $entry = simplexml_load_file('entry.xml');        
    printf("%s\n", $entry->children('job', true)->location->region);  
 ?>
```

To check the above code in action, click [here](http://codepad.org/f2tutLdx)

For more information about SimpleXml refer to this [article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/688)

Comment: Try it tonight (I write on mobile). And my XML file has lot entry nodes.

Comment: @Gordon. That's because the namespace isn't specified in my code snippet. Neither was that part of the question. It is assumed that the person who asked the question is already aware of how to specify namespaces. Anyways thanks for -1

Comment: @Hasan the namespace is the only issue here and that is fetched with `->children('job', true)->location` and not with `->job->location`. Your snippet wouldnt work even if there wasnt a namespace at all because there is no job element. As for the downvote: you cant complain about a dv when the answer is wrong. Correct it and I will happily revoke the dv.

Answer (score 1):

You should [register the job namespace](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php), then you can use the registered namespace-prefix in an XPath to select what you want:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('job', 'http://example.org/you-did-not-provide-the-job-namespaceURI-in-your-example');
$result = $sxe->xpath('//entry/job:location/job:region');

foreach ($result as $location) {
  echo $location . "\n";
}
```

Comment: If entry node has nodes without namespaces? How I can iterating through all entry node contains nodes with and without namespaces?

Comment: If you want to match on an `entry` element, whether or not it is bound to a namespace, you can match on the `local-name()`: `*[local-name()='entry']`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it dynamically.

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_string($path) // loads your valid xml data
foreach($xml->channel->item as $entry) {

  $namespaces = $entry->getNameSpaces(true);
  foreach($namespaces as $ns=>$value)
  {
    $job = $entry->children($namespaces[$ns]);
    $author = (string)$job->creator;

    if ($author != "")
    {
      $someVariable = (string) $dc->creator;
    }
}
```