# php simple xml element with : in it is not showing up

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SimpleXML and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843025/simplexml-and-namespaces)

I am using Simple XML to try and process a response XML.

I notice many elements missing and noticed that they all have a ":" in the element name.

For example:

- <updated>2012-12-14T18:17:53.670Z</updated>"
- <app:edited>2012-12-14T18:17:53.670Z</app:edited>

<updated> shows up in the object

<app:edited> does **not**

Simply removing the : makes the element show up however I am not so impressed with such a solution.

The php code I am using from the point of the response is :

$response = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponse);
var_dump($response);

Any help and to explain this behaviour is well appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at XML namespaces: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/

Comment: In `<app:edited>` the element is named `edited` and it resides in the namespace `app`. See this related question for a usage example for XML namespaces and PHP simplexml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843025/simplexml-and-namespaces