# Cannot convert XML to Object in PHP - returns empty object

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

Below is the XML that I am trying to convert using `simplexml_load_string()`.

```
$THE_XML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <ns:getMarketsByNpaNxxResponse xmlns:ns="http://ws.inventory.ccds.com" xmlns:ax251="http://exceptions.commons.ccds.com/xsd" xmlns:ax250="http://exceptions.ccds.com/xsd" xmlns:ax260="http://availability.item.productsservices.ccds.com/xsd" xmlns:ax259="http://detail.item.productsservices.ccds.com/xsd" xmlns:ax264="http://item.productsservices.ccds.com/xsd" xmlns:ax257="http://ws.inventory.ccds.com/xsd" xmlns:ax255="http://security.ccds.com/xsd"><ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax257:Market">
    <ax257:marketId>30</ax257:marketId>
    <ax257:marketName>AZ-FLAGSTAFF</ax257:marketName> 
    <ax257:npaNxxs>928863</ax257:npaNxxs>
    </ns:return>
  </ns:getMarketsByNpaNxxResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


$RESULT = simplexml_load_string($THE_XML);

var_dump($RESULT);
```

Returns:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (0) {
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not an empty object - `SimpleXMLElement` has its own implementation of `var_dump()` that doesn't usually show recursive nodes. It would be `(bool)false` if it failed to load.

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve the namespaced child nodes?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would show the results of the returned XML object?

Comment: If you understand XML namespaces and how SimpleXML handles them, these should set you on your way. Some examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027398/php-simplexml-namespace-problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843025/simplexml-and-namespaces  Important for you is to `$RESULT->children('soapenv', true)->Body->children('ns', true)->getMarketsByNpaNxxResponse->children('ax257', true)->marketName`

Comment: Thanks that example really helped - but this is so coarse to parse - it seems overly difficult :/

Comment: That's one of the big reasons JSON is winning out over XML these days. JSON REST services are so much more easily implemented  on both client & server than SOAP/XML.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Holy War time! ;) It's perfectly possible to write succinct XML that's not as pointlessly bloated as SOAP (and to use it with REST too!) It's also perfectly possible to write hideously confusing JSON, and I've seen people doing just that. Just sayin'...